# niceselect JS: How to manipulate 'current' element on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For our shops we use the NiceSelect library, but we ran into an issue:

When we try to override a DOM element in the new selection-dropdown for our payment options, our changes get overriden right back. This only happens to the element called 'current', which I will explain down below:

**CODE**

```
//Make the generated select into a nice select
$('#payment_type').niceSelect();

//Add additional fees to items, where needed, and bind an event to those items
if(!additionalFeesAdded){
    $('.nice-select.small.payment_type ul > li').each(function(i){
        var af = additionalFeeArray[i];
        if(af != "NaN" && af != "0.00"){
            $(this).append("<label class='additional-fee selection'> + € " + af + "</label>");
            $(this).on('click', function(){
                $('.nice-select.small.payment_type .current').trigger('contentchanged');
            });
        }
    });

    //Hocus pocus to make the additional fee float to the right (TEST DATA)
    $('.nice-select.small.payment_type .current').bind('contentchanged', function(){
        var paymentType = "Method";
        var additionalFee = "Fee";

        console.log($(this).html()); //Returns DOM before change
        $(this).html(paymentType + "<label class='additional-fee'>" + additionalFee + "</label>");
        console.log($(this).html()); //Returns DOM after change
    });
}

additionalFeesAdded = true;
```

**DOM SETUP**

```
<div class="nice-select small payment_type open" tabindex="0">
    <span class="current">SELECTED OPTION APPEARS HERE</span>
    <ul class="list">
        <li data-value="" class="option selected focus">Select a payment type </li>
        <li data-value="3" class="option">OPT.1<label class="additional-fee selection"> + € 0.60</label></li>
        <li data-value="4" class="option">OPT.2</li>
        <li data-value="6" class="option">OPT.3<label class="additional-fee selection"> + € 0.40</label></li>
        <li data-value="27" class="option">OPT.4<label class="additional-fee selection"> + € 0.50</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is pretty much what's being done to make an additional fee float to the right. This works in the ***li*** items the library makes, but not the DOM element that shows the selected option.

I tried adding a custom event to mimic an **onChange()**, but the latter DOM printed to the console never makes it to the element itself:

How the element always comes back:

[image]

How it should be:
[image]

So in short: Something I try to manipulate doesn't want to get manipulated, and I don't know what's going wrong. Is anyone able to help me with/see the issue?

If more information is required, I am happy to oblige.

Comment: Please don't use `bind()` .. _As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged_.

Comment: what css rule do you use to shift fee to the right? May be it includes `ul` or `li` so it doesn't affect `.current`

Comment: @Grin The code rules I use are:

.additional-fee{
 float: right;
}
.additional-fee.selection{
  margin-right: 7px;
}

I'm not targeting the *.current* directly -I'm basically trying to inject a new DOM set into it, just like I have done with the *li* items.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks for the tip. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice select library replace `.current` text after option has been changed. 
You need to call your handler after the library did its work.

So remove `click` binding in cycle and `contentchanged` handler.

And add `click` handler like this

```
  $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select .option:not(.disabled)', function(event) {

       $current = $('.nice-select  .current');

        var paymentType = "Method";
        var additionalFee = "Fee";

        console.log($current.html()); //Returns DOM before change
        $current.html(paymentType + "<label class='additional-fee'>" + additionalFee + "</label>");
        console.log($current.html()); //Returns DOM after change

     });
```

I made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EQeWqw5BROajACZEwkKa?p=preview) with working example

Comment: this worked like a charm! I had to do some minor editing (mainly the name of the class I was targeting), but it's all working like it should, now.

Answer (score 0):

I check the code but the following part does not work for me:

```
$current = $('.nice-select  .current');
```

Then I change the .current to .selected and it returns the selected li element, maybe this is a change in the new version of nice-select.